# VBA solution of VIF factors [EXCEL]

Tags: excel, regression

I have several multiple linear regressions to carry out, I am wondering if there is a VBA solution for getting the VIF of regression outputs for different equations.

My current data format:

```
i=1

Year   DependantVariable Variable2 Variable3 Variable4 Variable5 ....
2009      100               10         20       -
2010      110               15         25       -
2011      115               20         30       -
2012      125               25         35       -
2013      130               25         40       -
```

I have the above table, with the value of i determining the value of the variables (essentially, different regression input tables in place for every value of i)

I am looking for a VBA that will check every value of i (stored in a column), calculate the VIF for every value of i and output something like below

```
ivalue variable1VIF variable2VIF ...
1          1.1          1.3
2          1.2          10.1
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it using regular Excel? Just record what you are doing and you have the corresponding VBA macro.

Comment: "I am looking for a VBA ..."  - not how this site works. Please see [ask] and [reprex].